# Using Stripe in credit card payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to process online payment in our website using credit cards like visa and master card. Is [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) api the perfect solution for this and can support all types of cards world wide?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe can support almost any kind of credit or debit card. It also supports Bitcoin, Apple Pay, Android Pay, 3D Secure, SOFORT, iDEAL, Giropay, Bancontact, SEPA direct debit, and China’s Alipay.

Please refer this link for more info on Stripe:  https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-cards-and-payment-types-can-i-accept-with-stripe

Comment: but as listed here https://stripe.com/global they says that its available in 25 countries only.

Comment: That means that you can only create your account(to receive payouts from your balance to your bank account) in one of those countries, but you can accept payments from anywhere across the world.